# An always open app showing the current date and time

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am making an app which is going to be always open into my tablet. I am trying to show the current date and time in real time. For the time, I use below code

```
<DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
```

And it works perfectly. The app is always open and the time change in real-time 
*(although I am searching now how to add the seconds)*.

For the date, I used that code

```
dateTimeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy");
date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getInstance().getTime());
dateTimeDisplay.setText(date);
```

But it shows the current date, not in real-time. It changes only when I open the app.

I can tell because I put seconds in dateFormat to test it and it was static.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy , ss");
```

Have anyone any idea?? Thank you!!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it was helpful (and not to if it wasn’t). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

***[DigitalClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock) has been deprecated, It is recommended you use [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock) instead.***

[TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock) will do your job by default. Check below example

```
<TextClock
        android:id="@+id/textClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
        android:textColor="#F1511B"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and for 24-hour format use

```
android:format24Hour="hh:mm:ss a
```

---

**`Improvement note:`** Instead of using SimpleDateFormat and helper classes you should use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) as Ole V.V. is indicating in the comment. Here is [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Comment: Thank you, I will make the change.. Do you have maybe any idea for the date?

Comment: I just made the change but it shows the same.. Only hour and minutes.. Not seconds.. But at least it is real time..

Comment: I changed it to android:format24Hour="hh:mm:ss a" and it works! Thank you again!